# How do i delete a slash command from discord.js client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I added two slash commands accidently and I tried to delete it by

```js
guild.commands.delete("Id")
```

but it requires ID and I couldn't get Id of an client command

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i think something like this solution would work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69171716/13269697

```
guild.commands.delete('123456789012345678')
```

and you get your command id via something like this in the replies:

```
guild.commands.cache.forEach((value, key) => { 
  // key is then your id or do value.id
  console.log(value.id)
})
```

[ApplicationCommandManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommandManager)

also, make sure you did remove the duplicate in your code if you didn't already or it'll just re-appear the next time you push commands

edit:

you could just reset all of the commands and then repush them if that's easier. then remove this line so it doesn't always reset.

```
client.application.commands.set([])
```